# reshaping a data frame duplicating IDs

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape2, tidyr

This is my dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3), A1 = c("a1","a3","a5"), 
B1 = c("b1","b3","b5"), A2 = c("a2","a4","a6"), B2 = c("b2","b4","b6"))
```

And the result I want is this:

```
  ID  A  B
1  1 a1 b1
2  1 a2 b2
3  2 a3 b3
4  2 a4 b4
5  3 a5 b5
6  3 a6 b6
```

I tried to approach to a solution, but I had no luck.

Comment: `reshape(df, dir = 'long', sep = '', varying = -1)[, c('ID','A','B')]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `melt` from `data.table` which can take multiple `measure` `patterns` to convert from 'wide' to 'long' format.

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(df), measure = patterns("^A", "^B"), 
          value.name = c("A", "B"))[, variable := NULL][order(ID)]
#  ID  A  B
#1:  1 a1 b1
#2:  1 a2 b2
#3:  2 a3 b3
#4:  2 a4 b4
#5:  3 a5 b5
#6:  3 a6 b6
```